# Access host chrome from vscode devcontainer

Tags: docker, google-chrome, vscode-devcontainer

I am wondering if there is a way to access the chrome installed on host machine(Mac) from vscode devcontainer?

I have a devcontainer.json file as follows

```json
{
    "name": "Node.js",
    "build": {
        "dockerfile": "Dockerfile"
    },
    "remoteEnv": {
        "TEST": "${localEnv:TEST}",
        "CHROME_BIN": "${containerEnv:PATH}:/Applications/'Google Chrome.app'/Contents/MacOS/'Google Chrome'"
    }
}
```

I want to run jasmine tests from the container which is expecting "CHROME_BIN" env variable which is pointing to chrome binary.

When I spin-up the container with the above configuration, karma launcher is unable to find chrome(In other words the docker container is unable to locate host machine's chrome with `CHROME_BIN` variable I set).

BTW I do not want to run chrome in headless mode inside my docker container.